# Mypy type annotations for a decorator

Tags: python, decorator, mypy

I have a decorator class but am having trouble adding type annotations to it.

```
import functools

class LogInfo:

    def __init__(self, environment: str):
        self.environment = environment

    def __call__(self, func):
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def decorated(*args, **kwargs):
            # My Stuff goes here...
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorated
```

Closest I can get is this:

```
import functools
from collections import Callable
from typing import TypeVar, Any

GenericReturn = TypeVar("GenericReturn")
GenericCallable = TypeVar("GenericCallable", bound=Callable[..., GenericReturn])


class LogInfo:
    def __init__(self, environment: str) -> None:
        self.environment = environment

    def __call__(self, func: GenericCallable) -> GenericCallable:
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def decorated(*args: Any, **kwargs: Any) -> GenericReturn:
            # My Stuff goes here...
            return func(*args, **kwargs)
        return decorated  # LINE 29
```

But I still get this error:

```
29: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Callable[..., Any]", expected "GenericCallable")
```

Removing the `@functools.wraps(func)` changes the error to:

```
29: error: Incompatible return value type (got "Callable[[VarArg(Any), KwArg(Any)], GenericReturn]", expected "GenericCallable")
```

Comment: Looks like you just need to declare a decorator as usual (return the same type as the input), no? (what's that `GenericReturn` for?)

Comment: Don't define `GenericCallable` as a generic variable, but just as `GenericCallable = Callable[..., GenericReturn]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a decent solution:

```
import functools
from collections import Callable
from typing import TypeVar, cast, Any

T = TypeVar("T", bound=Callable[..., Any])


class LogInfo:
    def __init__(self, environment: str):
        self.environment = environment

    def __call__(self, func: T) -> T:
        @functools.wraps(func)
        def decorated(*args, **kwargs):  # type: ignore
            # My Stuff goes here...
            return func(*args, **kwargs)

        return cast(T, decorated)
```

We can test this with the follow code:

```
@LogInfo(environment="HI")
def foo(input: str) -> str:
    return f"{input}{input}"

# NOTE: Intentional error here to trigger mypy
def bar() -> int:
    return foo("jake")
```

As expected, we get this `mypy` error:

```
error: Incompatible return value type (got "str", expected "int")
```

Remaining things that could be improved:

- The `return cast(T, decorated)` is ugly.
- Typing args & kwargs would be good.

Comment: To solve the two mentioned problems from Python 3.10 on one can use [ParamSpec](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#typing.ParamSpec)